# Python Yes/No User Input

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I am trying to create a user input for writing to a file the current code works but i have to write my answer with ' ' around them is there anyway i can just write yes or Y without having to include ' '

```
Join = input('Would you like to write to text file?\n')
if Join in ['yes', 'Yes']:
    for key, value in ip_attacks.iteritems(): #for key(the IPAddress) and value(the occurrence of each IPAddress) in ip_attacks 
        if value > 30: #if the value (number of occurrences) is over 30  
            myTxtFile.write('\n{}\n'.format(key)) #then we want to write the key(the IPAdress) which has been attack more than 30 times to the text file
else:
    print ("No Answer Given")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `raw_input` instead:

```
Join = raw_input('Would you like to write to text file?\n')
```

`raw_input` gets what the input was as a string, while `input` gets the exact user input and evaluates it as Python. The reason you're having to put "Yes" rather than Yes is because you need to make the input evalute as a string. `raw_input` means that you don't need to do that.

### Note for Python 3.x

`raw_input` was changed to `input` in Python 3.x. If you need the old functionality of `input`, use `eval(input())` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `input` in Python 2.x; use `raw_input`. `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))`, which means you have to type a string which forms a valid Python expression.

In Python 3, `raw_input` was renamed `input`, and the former `input` was removed from the language. (You rarely want to evaluate the input as an expression; when you do, you can just call `eval(input(...))` yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your if statement to use lower() or upper() to compare with the string and not have to use the single quotes around the 'yes' or 'y' as indicated below

```
if Join.lower() == 'yes' or Join.lower() == 'y':
```

If using Python3, try this:

```
Join = input('Would you like to write to text file?\n')
if Join.lower() == 'yes' or Join.lower() == 'y':
    for key, value in ip_attacks.iteritems(): #for key(the IPAddress) and value(the occurrence of each IPAddress) in ip_attacks
        if value > 30: #if the value (number of occurrences) is over 30
            myTxtFile.write('\n{}\n'.format(key)) #then we want to write the key(the IPAdress) which has been attack more than 30 times to the text file
else:
    print ("No Answer Given")
```

Otherwise if using Python2, as others have stated you would want to use raw_input() instead of just input()

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input` instead. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

So in your first line you would use:

```
Join = raw_input('Would you like to write to text file?\n')
```