# Using panda to convert string "yes" to 1 but failed

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to convert "Yes"and "No" from column"ServiceLevel" to "1" and "0".
This is my code:

```
mydata['ServiceLevel'].replace(to_replace ='Yes',value = 1,inplace = 'True')

mydata['ServiceLevel'].replace(to_replace ='No', value = 0,inplace = 'True')

mydata['ServiceLevel'].head()
```

ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type str.

What's this mean? How to correct it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Yes/No User Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018207/python-yes-no-user-input)

Comment: What about a `mydata["ServiceLevel"] = mydata["ServiceLevel"].apply(lambda x:True if x == 'Yes' else False)`, Inplace takes a boolean and not string ('True' is a string in your example)

Answer (score 1):

`inplace` is a boolean argument - it takes either `True` or `False`, but you passed the **string** `'True'` (note the quotes). Remove the quotes to get a boolean literal, and you should be fine:

```py
mydata['ServiceLevel'].replace(to_replace ='Yes', value = 1, inplace = True)
mydata['ServiceLevel'].replace(to_replace ='No', value = 0, inplace = True)
# Here ---------------------------------------------------------------^---^
```

Comment: Please don't recommend the use of inplace - especially for Dataframe columns as it can lead to unintended side effects (most notably the setting with copy warning, or actually preventing the operation from updating the column in-place). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384/4909087